# Pass Classname to GenericMethod<T>, when the className is stored as String

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm currently dealing with a requirement to a pass Class to a GenericMethod as T. But I get my className as string parameter. When I know the className at Compile time, I have no issue.
But I'm struck passing the className as T to the GenericMethod when I receive the className in string parameter..

How can I pass the className as a Class to the GenericMethod
ChildClass_1: ParentClass

```
public override void CallGenericMethod(string currentClassName)
{
   var type = Type.GetType(currentClassName);
   GenericMethod<type>(typeOf(type).Name);
}
```

ParentClass.cs

```
 public virtual void GenericMethod<type>(string className){
   console.WriteLine("Invoked ClassName");
 }
```

Could anyone please help me in resolving this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: @Charlieface, will check and update the comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to build generic method in runtime:

```
public void CallGenericMethod(string currentClassName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(currentClassName);
    var methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(GenericMethod));
    methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(typeOf(type).Name);
}
```

null safety is omitted